# Move to next cell on key enter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell, enter

I need to change the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key functionality in a datagridview , I want to prevent it to go to a new line I need it to move to the next cell I have tried a lot of logic to do this without success the last one of them was

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        int col = dgvPayments.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int row = dgvPayments.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (col < dgvPayments.ColumnCount - 1)
        {
            col++;
        }
        else
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

        if (row == dgvPayments.RowCount)
            dgvPayments.Rows.Add();

        dgvPayments.CurrentCell = dgvPayments[col, row];
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

that works great when only press <kbd>Enter</kbd> not after edit a cell , 
If I enter a cell and edit it and press the key <kbd>Enter</kbd> it goes to the next row and the column after I was in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {                
            e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
            int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (iColumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count-1)
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
            else
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];

        }
    }
```

Comment: same problem here , works when moving from cell to another , when editing and cell and press enter go to a new row !